# What's the difference between EOSIO and EvolutionOS?

Tags: airdrops

I'm confused about [EvolutionOS](https://www.evolutionos.com/) and how does it different from EOS.IO?

On their website we can read it's not the fork.

> Are you forking EOS? No, as there are no live blockchains running EOS software.

and at the same time I can't find any source code related to *EvolutionOS*, so how it's different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their goal is the keep the blockchain decentralized. Meaning they will launch their own chain with the same software, with the goal of having different block producers than the main chain.

The only difference is that instead of 1 billion tokens, they'll have 5 billion tokens.

Keep in mind that EOS.IO is designed to enable multiple implementations, with different governing structures.

I think evolutionOS is not doing all that much to distinguish themselves as of now, but I can imagine future implementation of EOS making drastic changes to the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

EvolutionOS has a certain opinion on how a blockchain should be governed which is different from that of EOSIO's.

For instance, it was earlier proposed by EOSIO that a token owner must lock up their tokens for a period of 6 months before they have voting power. EvolutionOS believed this to be unfair as those who have more wealth can afford to lock up their tokens longer.

See: [EOS Voting, 6 Month Lockup Period and Token Reward](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/81ac0z/eos_voting_6_month_lockup_period_and_token_reward/).

This was later altered by the governance model of EOSIO and was brought down to 3 days through an announcement on Telegram by Daniel Larimer.